# Shift left operation on uint64_t gives above error when shift above 30 bits

Tags: c++, bit

When i use shift left in uint64_t variable, like `mask = 1 << 31` or above, all bits left turn 1;

I'm using: 
Ubuntu 22.04; 
gnu++23; 
Vscode with c_cpp extension;

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    uint64_t mask1{1};
    uint64_t mask2{1};

    mask1 = 1 << 30; // OK 1000000000000000000000000000000
    mask2 = 1 << 31; // ERROR 1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000
    // Expecting 10000000000000000000000000000000


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `1` is an integer literal - you need an unsigned long literal. Change `1 << 31` to `1UL << 31`.

Comment: @PaulR Or `1uLL` on platforms like MSVC, where an `unsigned long` is only 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
mask2 = 1 << 31;
```

First the expression on the right side is evaluated, and then assigned to `mask2`.
Since `1` is an `int` literal, the expression in evaluated as a 32 bit `int`.

Change it as following to achieve what you what:

```
mask2 = static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << 31;
```

It will perform the shift considering `1` as an unsigned 64 bit value.

Another option with a similar result is:

```
mask2 = 1ULL << 31;
```